# Kivy Button macro w get screen instructions

Tags: kivy

looking to set up a reusable button in my kivy file that includes various root.manager.get_screen instructions under on_press ... Anyone know if this is possible to do in the kv?  Thanks so much for any help in advance

```
<ProductButton@Button>
    color: 'black'
    outline_color: 'white'
    outline_width: 15
    on_press:
        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        root.manager.transition.duration = 1
        root.manager.current = (root.ids.product1.text+root.ids.label.text+'Detail') 
        root.manager.get_screen(root.manager.MY_GLOBAL).ids.selection.background_normal = self.background_normal
```

etc.

The code works in the individual screens but it is long and ugly so I would like to set up a macro instead...

Here is the error I get -
AttributeError: 'ProductButton' object has no attribute 'manager'

Comment: In you example `kv`, the `root` refers to the `ProductButton` instance. You need to get a reference to the `ScreenManager`, but without more of your code, that can't be determined.

Comment: Thanks for commenting John!  I switched my references here in the kv to app.root instead and that works.  Next time I'll try and provide a little more code.